# Stop encoding a video from piped video and directshow audio data

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, node-streams

Via node.js I'm spawning a FFmpeg process which generates a video using jpeg images received from a node.js stream. Additionally it records audio from a directshow device.

```
const child = require("child_process");
const stream = require("stream");
let inputStream = new stream.PassThrough();
let ffmpeg = child.spawn("ffmpeg.exe", [
    "-f", "image2pipe", "-r", "24", "-fflags", "nobuffer",
    "-i", "pipe:0",
    "-f", "dshow",
    "-sample_rate",
    "48000",
    "-i", 'audio="Microphone"',
    "-acodec",
    "pcm_s16le",
    "-ac", "2",
    "-ar", "48000",
    "-vcodec", "libx264",
    "-crf", "10",
    "-preset", "veryfast",
    "-framerate", "1",
    "output.mkv"
]);

inputStream.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);
```

The problem is, if I later stop sending images down the pipe

```
inputStream.end();
```

to ultimately stop FFmpeg from encoding the video, it does **not** stop - I guess because it's still grabbing audio data from the directshow device.

After digging through the FFmpeg manual I've found the `-shortest` output options which should:

> ...Finish encoding when the shortest output stream ends...

So upon adding the option e.g.

```
...
    "-preset", "veryfast",
    "-framerate", "1",
    "-shortest"
    "output.mkv"
]);
```

it indeed stops encoding but it's happening too fast.

So a video worth 10 seconds of data just has 5 seconds of audio and from second 5 - 10 there's just silence. I assume it's happening because it doesn't drain the rest of the audio buffer before stopping.

How can I stop encoding the output from the video and the audio data, while keeping all the data up to the point I've triggered the 'stop'?

Comment: You have `"-r", "24",` and then `"-framerate", "1",` . What are those for? How fast are you supplying the images?

Comment: @Gyan Indeed that's a parameter I was not sure about (if it means how many frames per second or how many frames are sent per write). I'm delivering the images at the `-r` rate e.g. 24 frames a second in this case.